# Async Function in Controller of Old State Executes Code In New State

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have 2 states. In state A, I have an async $http call, which after resolving, does something (like reloading the state). Before this $http is resolved, I transition to state B. The onDestroy event of state A's controller clearly shows that the scope is destroyed before the resolution of the $http call and I transition to state B. However, once the original $http is resolved, code in that function is still executed, reloading state B.

Is this normal/expected behavior?

If so, how to ensure this is avoided?

A simple example to demonstrate this is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/G4cR9lP4cD0g1hj51T3K?p=preview. I modified the hello and about components of ui-router's hello galaxy example. In either hello or about state, click the async button, which will fire a setTimeout of 5s wrapped in a promise, and reload the state. Before timeout is reached change state. That state will be reloaded!

Hello component:

```
  angular.module('hello').component('hello', {
  template: '<h3>{{$ctrl.greeting}} galaxy!</h3>' + ' <input type="button" value="Async Hello" ng-click="$ctrl.asyncBegin()">' +
  '<button ng-click="$ctrl.toggleGreeting()">toggle greeting</button> ',

  controller: function ($state) {
    this.greeting = 'hello';
    this.$onInit = async () => {

    }
    this.toggleGreeting = function () {
      this.greeting = (this.greeting == 'hello') ? 'whats up' : 'hello'
    }
    this.$onDestroy = () => {
      console.log('ENDING HELLO STATE');
    }
    this.asyncBegin = async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('TIMEOUT IN HELLO');
          $state.reload();
          resolve();
        }, 5000);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

About component:

```
  angular.module('hello').component('about', {
  template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router "Hello Galaxy" app!</h3> <input type="button" value="Async About" ng-click="$ctrl.asyncBegin()">',
  controller: function ($state) {
    this.$onInit = async () => {

    }

    this.$onDestroy = () => {
      console.log('ENDING ABOUT STATE');
    }

    this.asyncBegin = async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('TIMEOUT IN ABOUT');
          $state.reload();
          resolve();
        }, 5000);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This seems like the expected behaviour, it's your role to verify that you dont launch 2 async processes that can conflict. I guess this is the reason `setTimeout` is executed from globals, so that the timeout is not cancelled when the scope that fired it is deleted, or else timeouts would not be reliable.. You can set a variable that you check in the async process to know if the action should be cancelled or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is expected behavior.
No, there is no way to handle this in general - you should handle each case in some way.
In this concrete case, it seems logical to cancel timeout in `this.$onDestroy` method.

If this case is very common in your app, you can write some service, that will cancel your timeouts under some conditions.(state change, url change, etc.)

Comment: Timeout here were only shown as a demonstrable example of an async task. In my application, these will be $http calls.

Comment: for $http you can first cancel http request or check in callback that component is not destroyed, or move this logic to service